# Does camel-ssh use .ssh/config?

Tags: apache, ssh, apache-camel

Does camel-ssh use the configuration specified in $HOME/.ssh/config file?

If not, can options like "StrictHostKeyChecking" be passed in camel-ssh somehow?

I'm stuck debugging another problem and not yet able to run camel-ssh yet. Wondering if anybody else has used it successfully?

I'm planning to implement a OSGI bundle in karaf that uses camel-ssh to ssh out to remote servers and execute commands on them?

Update: 
I tried it and it does not seem to use the .ssh/config file

My ssh URI:

```
ssh:host:22?username=xx&certResource=file:/Users/xxx/.ssh/id_rsa&timeout=300000
```

There is an entry in .ssh/config file for 'host'

The exception is

```
Exchange[ExchangePattern: InOnly, BodyType: String, Body: uname -a 2>&1 , CaughtExceptionType: org.apache.camel.CamelExchangeException, CaughtExceptionMessage: Cannot execute command: uname -a 2>&1 . Exchange[Message: uname -a 2>&1 ]. Caused by: [java.nio.channels.UnresolvedAddressException - null], StackTrace: org.apache.camel.CamelExchangeException: Cannot execute command: uname -a 2>&1 . Exchange[Message: uname -a 2>&1 ]. Caused by: [java.nio.channels.UnresolvedAddressException - null]
    at org.apache.camel.component.ssh.SshProducer.process(SshProducer.java:43)
    at org.apache.camel.util.AsyncProcessorConverterHelper$ProcessorToAsyncProcessorBridge.process(AsyncProcessorConverterHelper.java:61)
    at org.apache.camel.processor.RedeliveryErrorHandler.process(RedeliveryErrorHandler.java:448)
    at org.apache.camel.processor.CamelInternalProcessor.process(CamelInternalProcessor.java:191)
    at org.apache.camel.processor.MulticastProcessor.doProcessSequential(MulticastProcessor.java:590)
    at org.apache.camel.processor.MulticastProcessor.doProcessSequential(MulticastProcessor.java:518)
    at org.apache.camel.processor.MulticastProcessor.process(MulticastProcessor.java:227)
    at org.apache.camel.processor.RecipientList.sendToRecipientList(RecipientList.java:167)
    at org.apache.camel.processor.RecipientList.process(RecipientList.java:120)
    at org.apache.camel.processor.Pipeline.process(Pipeline.java:118)
    at org.apache.camel.processor.Pipeline.process(Pipeline.java:80)
    at org.apache.camel.management.InstrumentationProcessor.process(InstrumentationProcessor.java:77)
    at org.apache.camel.processor.RedeliveryErrorHandler.process(RedeliveryErrorHandler.java:448)
    at org.apache.camel.processor.CamelInternalProcessor.process(CamelInternalProcessor.java:191)
    at org.apache.camel.processor.Pipeline.process(Pipeline.java:118)
    at org.apache.camel.processor.Pipeline.process(Pipeline.java:80)
    at org.apache.camel.processor.CamelInternalProcessor.process(CamelInternalProcessor.java:191)
    at org.apache.camel.component.seda.SedaConsumer.sendToConsumers(SedaConsumer.java:291)
    at org.apache.camel.component.seda.SedaConsumer.doRun(SedaConsumer.java:200)
    at org.apache.camel.component.seda.SedaConsumer.run(SedaConsumer.java:147)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: java.nio.channels.UnresolvedAddressException
    at sun.nio.ch.Net.checkAddress(Net.java:123)
    at sun.nio.ch.UnixAsynchronousSocketChannelImpl.implConnect(UnixAsynchronousSocketChannelImpl.java:301)
    at sun.nio.ch.AsynchronousSocketChannelImpl.connect(AsynchronousSocketChannelImpl.java:209)
    at org.apache.sshd.common.io.nio2.Nio2Connector.connect(Nio2Connector.java:46)
    at org.apache.sshd.SshClient.connect(SshClient.java:297)
    at org.apache.sshd.SshClient.connect(SshClient.java:283)
    at org.apache.camel.component.ssh.SshEndpoint.sendExecCommand(SshEndpoint.java:88)
    at org.apache.camel.component.ssh.SshProducer.process(SshProducer.java:38)
```

Comment: Looks like you are trying to connect to a null string. `UnresolvedAddressException - null`

Comment: I see "Nio2Connector                    | 239 - org.apache.sshd.core - 0.13.0 | Connecting to host:22" I would like it to translate the "host" to the actual hostname by looking up $HOME/.ssh/config file.